# How long should I intake weight gainers?

Tags: weight-gain

I am trying to gain long-term (permanent) weight and got a weight gainer ([mutant mass](http://www.iammutant.com/products/mutantmass.php)), the bag specify:

- Over 1,060  calories per serving
- 2 shakes a day.

Is it possible or recommendable to intake 2 shakes everyday for long period of times couple of years), just like protein shakes?

By my understanding is that weight gainers, are effective in aumenting muscular mass but once you stop intaking (2  weeks - 1 month) you start going downhill (unless you consume same calory amount in food).  Which make sense since you reduce your calories intake and maintin/increase calory burn.

Is it healthy to keep using weight gainer?  Are weight gainers more like easily getting where you want and then just worry about maintaining your goal?

Answer (score 2):

Weight gainers don't necessarily "augment muscular mass", they are just calorie bombs. It's what you do with the calories that matters. A product like this does what it advertises, you gain weight. If you are not doing the workouts to support that amount of caloric intake, you'll gain it in fat. There is no "easily getting" to where you want, it all takes hard work.

Where it has an advantage is if you are doing massive amounts of workouts, and are limited on what/when you can eat. For example, Michael Phelps at peak training consumes in the range of 8-10,000 calories a day. For most dieticians, they shudder to see his daily plate, but he needs those calories to fuel his workouts and recovery. Probably 95% of the general public just doesn't need that many calories.

Also, remember that the vast majority of Phelp's workout regimen is very low impact cardio, I don't know if you could sustain 8,000 calories worth of straight weight workouts for very long without running into overuse/recovery issues.